# Elaticsearch data indexing using CURL

Tags: php, indexing, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to index all data from my db to ES, using curl without bulk indexer. I am indexing data record by record. It's working fine but when data is increased above around 80000 or more documents ES start skipping records. After skipping a few records it starts working again and then the same behaviour returns... Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Do you get any error message? If yes, please post it. Also: Are you using php-curl or command line curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing is a three step process.

1. Accept indexing request
2. Flush transaction file (index)
3. Refresh (recreates searcher, it's internal stuff but after refresh document is available for search, by default it's set to 1s)

In your case something may went wrong at each step. For example if indexing request are sent too fast some request may be rejected (but then you should see error).

Maybe documents are still in a transaction log (waiting for flush and you don't see them) there is a number of [index settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) to tweak this behavior. You're interested in following settings:

> `index.translog.flush_threshold_ops` When to flush based on operations.
>   `index.translog.flush_threshold_size` When to flush based on translog (bytes) size. 
>   `index.translog.flush_threshold_period` When to flush based on a period of not flushing. 
>   `index.translog.disable_flush`Disables flushing. Note, should be set for a short interval and then enabled.

As I said refresh by default happens every 1s but you can set it in index settings (`index.refresh_interval`). I usually disable refresh when indexing a lot of documents to improve indexing performance, see [disable refresh in ElasticSerach](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk) for more details.

From my experience ES is not loosing your documents, it's just they are not available for search yet. My peers often complain about same thing and I always replay "wait 5 minutes and check again", they are not coming back usually.

ElasticSearch sometimes is doing wired things when it has not enough memory. For example it's loosing fields in indexed documents (I saw question on SO like this, solution was to increase heap size). See [ElasticSearch configuration](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html)  for details.

Comment: You got the issue properly but here is a minor issue, that ES is skipping my request. I found it. 
I have checked my customized log where I found that server is not responding true or false after CURL request. Its completely skipping my records. For time being I used sleep function after indexing 10K records and now its working fine. 
I have used index.refresh_interval but it didn't worked for me. I am still looking into this issue for a proper solution.

Comment: I wonder if it's just ElasticSearch issue or maybe it's problem with stack they use to create API. Anyhow let us know if you find proper solution.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Mentioned issue is fixed in ES 1.4 but its a Beta version. wait_if_ongoing  Use this link http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-flush.html